# How to assign an additional/extra/second user-role to multiple users (of a specific user-role)

Tags: users, user-roles, bulk

I have 500 users with  50 of those users assigned to user-role XYZ. I'd like these 50 XYZ users to keep their current XYZ user-role **but also** be assigned another/additional/extra/second user-role ABC... as a bulk job.

I'm looking for a function that could

1. find all users with user-role XYZ
2. then assign them to a second user-role of ABC

Comment: So you want a user to have the capabilities of both roles? Have you tried creating a new role that has those capabilities? A role is just a group of capabilities, you can create a new group with new capabilities

Comment: No, the capabilities is not something I am concerned with. I only need an additional user-role assigned.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, a role is a collection of capabilities with a name, a user can be in 1 of these 'groups', it's a single value stored in the database not an array or list. To allow the user to do something more you give them a capability. It sounds like you're repurposing the roles and capabilities system as a 'job role' not just security, you would be better off with a profile feed or a user taxonomy. Keep in mind that taking your question literally using WP terminology doesn't make sense

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm not sure how _well_ they're actually supported, but WP does indeed accept multiple roles per user - the `{table_prefix}_capabiities` usermeta entry is always a serialized array of role names.

Comment: There are many plugins that can allocate more than one user role to a user. Whatever the capabilities are is not the issue, infact the capabilities may change. There are widget/menu visibility plugins that can be applied to different user roles. This is why I'm concerned with the user role not the capabilities.

Comment: I would check out the excellent [Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) plugin. @TomJNowell is correct, however IMO managing many different user roles grouped by different capabilities is far more cumbersome than just having the ability to add multiple user roles to a user, as you are trying to do. Members will do that for you.

Comment: Can Members assign an additional user-role to bulk users?

Comment: @brianjohnhanna unfortunately the Members plugin hasn't got the function I need as per my question. That is addition of an extra role to bulk/multiple users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this yourself by writing a simple function and hooking it it onto a user-related action (whether you want to do this once or on an ongoing basis will be up to you).

There are a couple different ways to trigger it, but perhaps the simplest I can think of would be to hook into the [`profile_update`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update) hook so that it would get run every time a user is saved. You could also hook into [`user_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) so it runs everytime a new user is added to ensure your data stays in sync. In order to test this out, then, you would want to try saving an existing user or creating a new user, as this will trigger the action hook.

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'wpse_assign_abc_role_to_xyz_users', 10 );
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse_assign_abc_role_to_xyz_users', 10 );

function wpse_assign_abc_role_to_xyz_users() {
   $args = array(
        'role'         => 'xyz', // Set the role you want to search for here
        'role__not_in' => array( 'abc' ), // If they already have abc role, we can skip them
        'number'       => '500', // Good idea to set a limit to avoid timeouts/performance bottlenecks
    ); 
    $xyz_users = get_users( $args );

    // Bail early if there aren't any to update
    if ( count( $xyz_users ) === 0 ) return;

    // get_users() returns an array of WP_User objects, meaning we can use the add_role() method of the object

    foreach ( $xyz_users as $user ) {
        $user->add_role( 'abc' );
    }
}
```

This would assume that you have already added the `abc` role using [`add_role`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) so that WP is aware of it.

Unfortunately, I am not available to test it right now but I will try and test later, however this should get you steered in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I added this to my functions.php, I've also made a new user-role with a repo plugin. It didn't seem to work?

Comment: @Pete I just tried it on a fresh copy of WP 4.7 using the `administrator` and `editor` roles. The code works as written. Did you update the user roles from `xyz` and `abc` to the actual role slugs? Did you update/save a user to trigger the hook? You can try adding `error_log( print_r( $xyz_users, true ) );` at the end of the function to see the output in the error log - there should be two entries under the role property. That is how I confirmed it worked.

Comment: Bingo, it worked. I might have played around with it a little too much. Your original function worked. Cheers. This is a very useful function. I've looked everywhere and there's nothing around that adds an extra role in bulk, so hopefully this will help others.